# How to set up httpd to accept "curl -T" uploads?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, centos

In the `curl` [manpage](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) they explain that it is possible to upload files to a website by

```
curl -T "{file1,file2}" http://www.uploadtothissite.com
curl -T "img[1-1000].png" ftp://ftp.picturemania.com/upload/
```

**Question**

How do I configure Apache to be accept uploads from `curl -T`?

Comment: What have you tried ? How did it not do what you wanted and are there any interesting related error or log messages ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have mod_dav enabled on your apache to support PUT requests.

Check http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dav.html for more information.

Answer (score 2):

From that same manual:

> **-T** ... If this is used on a HTTP(S) server, the PUT command  will be used. ...

HTTP PUT is typically associated with WebDAV, but you could also write a script in your favourite language, e.g. in [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php) or [Perl](http://www.apacheweek.com/issues/put1) and define that script as the PUT handler with for example:

```
Script PUT /put.php
```